# Modelstate.IsValid on listitems not working

Tags: asp.net-core, data-annotations, entity-framework-core, modelstate

I Have the following controller method

```
 public IActionResult Post([FromBody,Bind("Cursuscode","Duur","Titel")] IEnumerable<Cursus> cursussen)
 {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ImportResult ir = new ImportResult();
        //DoMoreAwesomeStuff...
        return Json(ir);
    }
    return new BadRequestResult();
 }
```

My `cursus class` looks like this

```
public class Cursus
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }        
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(10,ErrorMessage = "Code van de cursus is te lang")]
    public string Cursuscode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Duur { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(300, ErrorMessage = "Titel van de cursus is te lang")]
    public string Titel { get; set; }
}
```

So in my eyes the following post should return a bad request because of the cursuscode being to long. Instead Modelstate is valid. Why?

```
Cursus cursus = new Cursus() { Cursuscode = "123456789012", Duur = 5, Titel = "C# AAA" };

List<Cursus> cursussen = new List<Cursus>() { cursus };

// Act
result = cursussencontroller.Post(cursussen);
// Assert
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result,typeof(BadRequestResult));
```

Comment: are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid yes why?

Comment: So you tried `StringLength` and that still didn't break at ModelState? Check [this](http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling/max-length.html#maximum-length) out

Comment: You would have to manually add the model error as part of your unit test.  See this similar question for a detailed explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346866/model-state-validation-in-unit-tests