# Unit test controller model validation on AspNetCore

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In an ASPNET Core project I am trying to create some unit tests that would verify my data validation logic works fine.

My controller is very simple:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Track")]
public void Track([FromBody] DataItem item)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) throw new ArgumentException("Bad request");

    _dataItemSaver.SaveData(item);
}
```

I am using a test base class that would set up the `_myController` object as the controller under test.

```
    public ControllerTestBase()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"buildversion.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        _config = builder.Build();

        var services = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
            .AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseInMemoryDatabase();
            })
            .AddScoped<IDataItemSaver, DataItemSQLStorageService>()
            .AddScoped<MyController>()
            .Configure<MyConfig>(_config.GetSection(nameof(MyConfig)));

        services
            .AddMvc(mvcOptions =>
                {
                    mvcOptions.Filters.AddService(typeof(GlobalExceptionFilter), 0);
                });

        _additionalDISetupActions?.Invoke(services);

        _serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        _myController = _serviceProvider.GetService<MyController>();
    }
```

The test again is very simple:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Prop3Required()
    {
        // Arrange
        var dataItem = new DataItem()
        {
            Prop1 = "Prop1",
            Prop2 = "Prop2"
        };

        // Act & Assert
        Assert.ThrowsException<ArgumentException>(() => _myController.Track(dataItem));
    }
```

I am finding though that `ModelState.IsValid` is `true` when running a unittest even when my `DataItem` is missing required attributes (`Prop3` in this example). When testing the controller through the web with the same input, the validation works correctly (returning `false` for `ModelState.IsValid`).

How do I properly trigger the ASPNET Core logic for modelstate validation from a unit test?

Comment: Your not really going to throw an exception when `ModelState` is invalid are you?

Comment: I did, and handled the exception in a global exception filter to keep all error handling and formatting in the same place. Could move the check to a filter and apply globally but would keep the way to throw the exception and handle it in my global filter.

Comment: Seriously? Your method should be returning the view so the user can correct validation errors.

Comment: I did not mention that this is an API method. There's a designated error type (`ApiError`) that will contain modelstate errors. The `ApiError` object is assembled in my global exception filter based on the type of error encountered.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should take a look at Integration Testing  with ASP.NET Core (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing), it is a very simple way to host your application in a test context and test your entire pipeline.
As explained in the documentation you could do something like this in your test method:

```
_server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>());
_client = _server.CreateClient();
// Pass a not valid model 
var response = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync("Track", new DataItem());
Assert.IsFalse(response.IsSuccessStatusCode);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly I was looking for!

Comment: It's nice of you to mention TestServer and its integration testing capabilities, but the question was about a problem with unit testing.

Answer (score 20):

If you want to do a pure unit test you need to manually simulate the model state error because the model state validation is only triggered during runtime.

```
_myController.ModelState.AddModelError("yourItemFieldHere", "Your validation type here");
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing for more detail

Comment: Problem with this approach is that the test would still pass regardless of the presence of the `Required` data annotation attribute on the properties in the `DataItem` model.