# DotNet Core, How do I unit test a Controller Action method with a custom model binding

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit, xunit.net

With ASP.Net Core 2.2 I have a ModelBinder used in my PUT as follows:

```
[HttpPut("{taskIdentifier}/{number}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Put(string taskIdentifier, string number, 
            [ModelBinder(typeof(TaskUpdateV1Binder<TaskUpdate>))]TaskUpdate value)
```

At runtime, the TaskUpdateV1Binder is called,  It reads the request body and creates a TaskUpdate object.

I would like to unit test this.  I can't just call Put directly from the unit test because this bypasses the model binding.

I already have tests of the binder itself but I need to test it being used by the controller.
I am not testing MVC routing.

- I want a unit test that will fail if someone removes the ModelBinder
  annotation.
- Some properties are set by the binder (like ModelState.IsValid)
  and I want to ensure bad input produces the correct output.
- This does not have to use the actual model binder.  I can mock up one
  that does what I need.  If I do this, I still need at least one test to ensure the annotation is correctly applied in code.

Comment: You can't **unit test** it as controller action attributes are metadata use by the framework at run-time. You would need to do an **integration test** in order to test the desired behavior.

Comment: If you unit test the ModelBinder already, what's the purpose of unit testing it again in the controller. Since model binding happens before model validation and the result of that is passed to the controller action, I can't see a way you would unit test this because you're directly calling the controller action and not going through the routing module that would use the model binding attribute.

Comment: Someone removed the binding and forgot to put it back.  Then they  checked it in, and all the unit tests passed.  It was deployed.  I've fixed it, but I want a test to ensure this does not happen again.  Also, there is a section of my code that checks ModelState.IsValid and tests never hit it.

Comment: If they were able to remove the model binding and it didn't fail the unit tests designed to test the model binding then you really have zero tests that test the model binding.

Comment: I mean I have test that test the modelBinder class.  Given the proepr inputs, it does what it should.  However, I don't have a way to test that it is used by the controller.  That is my question.

Comment: You should test whole web application "pipeline", which mean you should start a server, create http client and send request to the action you are testing.

Comment: Is it possible to create that server as a unit test?  I've only done that as an integration test after it's deployed.  I already have that test, but I want to stop breaking changes from getting checked it.  I have a gated checking that fails if unit tests fail.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible via an *integration* test which can be run **before** deployment. A similar question was asked on SO and answered nicely (IMHO) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43392792/8055878). Check it out if you'd like to see a brief explanation and example.

As suggested in that answer I also recommend you peruse the following documentation:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing